# PyQGIS: run two native processing tools in a for loop

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I try would like to run two native processing tools. The last of them should use the firs step. With this code I got an error that result_1 ist not defined. Is there an error in the result_1?

```
lyrs = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() # dictionary
outFolder = r"/home/lissiklaus/Downloads/its-test/"
for lyr in lyrs:
    print(lyr.name())
    inLy = r"/home/lissiklaus/Downloads/its-test/baeume.shp"#anpassen 1. Layer der Verschneidung
    ovLy = lyr#anpassen 2. Layer der Verschneidung
    resITS= os.path.join(outFolder, f"{lyr.name()}_reprojected.shp")#anpassen Ergebnis der Verschneidung
    parIts = {
        'INPUT':inLy,
        'OVERLAY':ovLy,
        'INPUT_FIELDS':['bpkte','ws'],#anpassen Felder des 1. Layer, die erhalten bleiben
        'OVERLAY_FIELDS':['tpl'],#anpassen Felder des 2. Layer, die erhalten bleiben
        'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX':'',
        'OUTPUT':'memory:',
        'GRID_SIZE':None
        }

    result1=processing.run("native:intersection",parIts )

    parFieldCalc = {
        'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(result_1['OUTPUT'].source(),
        'FIELD_NAME':'its_m2',
        'FIELD_TYPE':1,
        'FIELD_LENGTH':11,
        'FIELD_PRECISION':0,
        'FORMULA':' $area ',
        'OUTPUT':resITS
        }
    processing.runAndLoadResults("native:fieldcalculator",parFieldCalc)

print("Feddisch!")
```

Answer (score 2):

You defined `result1` (note no underscore "_"):

```
result1=processing.run("native:intersection",parIts )
```

But then try to use the variable `result_1` which you never defined:

```
result_1['OUTPUT'].source()
```

Change to:

```
result_1=processing.run("native:intersection",parIts )`
```

Comment: thx for that. I found the solution via [link](https://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/3/processing_algorithms_pyqgis.html at point 13)

Answer (score 1):

Here I got the solution
https://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/3/processing_algorithms_pyqgis.html

```
lyrs = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() # dictionary
outFolder = r"/home/lissiklaus/Downloads/its-test/"
for lyr in lyrs:
    print(lyr.name())
    inLy = r"/home/lissiklaus/Downloads/its-test/baeume.shp"#anpassen 1. Layer der Verschneidung
    ovLy = lyr#anpassen 2. Layer der Verschneidung
    resITS= os.path.join(outFolder, f"{lyr.name()}_reprojected.shp")#anpassen Ergebnis der Verschneidung
    parIts = {
        'INPUT':inLy,
        'OVERLAY':ovLy,
        'INPUT_FIELDS':['bpkte','ws'],#anpassen Felder des 1. Layer, die erhalten bleiben
        'OVERLAY_FIELDS':['tpl'],#anpassen Felder des 2. Layer, die erhalten bleiben
        'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX':'',
        'OUTPUT':'memory:',
        'GRID_SIZE':None
        }

    result=processing.run("native:intersection",parIts )
    itsRes = result['OUTPUT']

    parFieldCalc = {
        'INPUT':itsRes,
        'FIELD_NAME':'its_m2',
        'FIELD_TYPE':1,
        'FIELD_LENGTH':11,
        'FIELD_PRECISION':0,
        'FORMULA':' $area ',
        'OUTPUT':resITS
        }
    processing.runAndLoadResults("native:fieldcalculator",parFieldCalc )

print("Feddisch!")
```